# Is there any way to disable the "connect charger" dialog?

Tags: charging

When I unplug my phone from the charger, it pops up a dialog that it's low on power.

Is it possible to disable that? My charger isn't that good so it looks like it's going in and out the whole time. The phone is still charging but I can't use it because the dialog is model and steals control the whole time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its time you should replace your charger... or you may lose your battery in some days. Because when a charger seems to behave like this, the voltage fluctuations so frequently, might degrade your battery life.

Comment: So it could permanently kill the battery?

Comment: There is a high probability that your battery may get damaged due to intense voltage fluctualtions. That's why I recommended you to replace your charger as soon as possible.